# Cause activity in actionbar tabs

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I use action bar tabs android studio, his div on section and I want that touch section I cause scrolling activity! I dont want work with a fragments, I want see in my section scrolling activity.

Help please, because long time sit in this trouble.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

[**MainActivity.java**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW9YW.jpg):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  /**
   * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
   * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
   * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
   * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
   * may be best to switch to a
   * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
   */
  private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

  /**
   * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
   */
  private ViewPager mViewPager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  /**
   * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
   */
  public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
      PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
      fragment.setArguments(args);
      return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
      //TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
      //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
      return rootView;
    }
  }

  /**
   * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
   * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
   */
  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
      // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
      return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      // Show 3 total pages.
      return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      switch (position) {
        case 0:
          return "SECTION 1";
        case 1:
          return "SECTION 2";
        case 2:
          return "SECTION 3";
        case 3:
          return "Секція 4";
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**main_activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.vladislav.scrolable.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.vladislav.scrolable.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: activity inside an activity is not possible.

Comment: why? flipping section its event? yes? may be we have event can do call(cause) action?

Comment: you have to use fragment for this kind of scenario, and moreover why do you need an activity inside an activity?

Comment: "you have to use fragment for this kind of scenario, and moreover why do you need an activity inside an activity? " because in this part my application will be much more text about health. I can deal fragment and textView but scrolling activity will much better in this situation for my opinion

Comment: And you( himanshu1496) believe that actionbar  cause scrolling activity not possible?

Comment: did you mean something like [this animation](https://github.com/eure/citrus/blob/master/docs/gifs/coll.gif), but with [tab layout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout)?

Comment: @isnotmenow I want that my actionbar(analog your tab layout) at flipping opens in this section scrolling activity where I will write text!!!!!!!!!!! that all
scrolling activity its (your this animation link) and actionbar is [https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=actionbaractivity&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=705&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1pavlkMbOAhUHvBoKHRsmAOsQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=actionbar&imgdii=t-DWaO42n6URGM%3A%3Bt-DWaO42n6URGM%3A%3BwcCBBgAK_G69oM%3A&imgrc=t-DWaO42n6URGM%3A] link

Comment: @isnotmenow did you mean something like this animation, but with tab layout‌​?yes yes yes i take a photo on my first publication

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I really couldn't get what you want to do here. Could you please elaborate it, or make a diagram image to describe your need?

Comment: Ohh I see. pardon my previous comment, commenting before reading your next comment. 
You can achieve it by using CoordinatorLayout, and add your ViewPager with        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: Could you give us your activity xml layout?

Comment: @isnotmenow i add xml in my first publication

Comment: Try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to ScrollView in your fragment_main.xml. Try changing ScrollView with  NestedScrollView

Comment: @isnotmenow its not possible. what is app? i write but xml not see this

Comment: That is an attribute like in your main activity xml. Just add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your RelativeLayout at `fragment_main.xml`

Comment: @isnotmenow excuse me I'm realy dont anderstand because AndroStudoi not see this attribute. My project on github may be your watching?
https://github.com/honia19/Scrolable.git

Comment: @isnotmenow because I realy dont understand

Comment: You need to use `app` attribute because you need to use custom view for the scrolling. You can look the same pattern in your `main_activity.xml` with the following code: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. This layout behaviour connected to `AppBarLayout` in your `main_activity.xml`. When you scrolling a view with that `app:layout_behavior` applied, it will inform `AppBarLayout` to scroll too.

Comment: @isnotmenow I understand but I have four XML files. what you write is not asked in view of the XML file. I ask you to download my app and try it for yourself I'm not the first publication of all XML files uploaded. Please

Comment: Let me rectify myself. From your git, I conclude that: **First**, you want to use scrolling Activity (ScrollingActivity) without tab. **Second**, you want to use scrolling with Activity (ScrollingActivity) inside MainActivity. **Third**, you want to use scrolling within MainActivity with TabLayout and Fragment. Afaik, **Second** number can't be achieved because we can't use Activity inside Activity for scrolling (as other says). **First**, looks like you have achieved it. **Third**, it could works by adding NestedScrollView. Try [this Layout](http://pastebin.com/XKMMb9AD) for fragment_main.xml

Comment: @isnotmenow okay thanks I'm try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering with your code in git, we can make a scrollable TabLayout by changing the fragment_main.xml to:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.vladislav.scrolable.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    >


  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scrollView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

We must set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of `NestedScrollView` to `match_parent` so that we can scroll the layout when we scrolling up the TextView.

Remember that we need to add the following code to `NestedScrollView`:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to inform `AppBarLayout` about the scrolling.

Please look at your Scrolable project after my edit in [my Scrolable github](https://github.com/isnotmenow/Scrolable).

Sample picture after scrolling up:

[image: scrolling up]